Shopify PHP rest API throws 500
I installed Shopify rest admin API library for PHP using the below command
composer require shopify/shopify-api

Then I applied first step as mentioned in the document like below
Context::initialize(
        apiKey: '{API_KEY}',
        apiSecretKey: '{API_SECRET}',
        scopes: ['read_products'],
        hostName: 'hnu-demo-store.myshopify.com',
        sessionStorage: new FileSessionStorage('/tmp/php_sessions'),
        apiVersion: '2023-04',
        isEmbeddedApp: true,
        isPrivateApp: false,
);

After that I tried to create the session using the below script
$headers = [
     'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
];
$cookies = [];
$isOnline = true;

$session = Shopify\Utils::loadCurrentSession(
    $headers,
    $cookies,
    $isOnline
);

I have used these on the top of the script
use Shopify\ApiVersion;
use Shopify\Auth\FileSessionStorage;
use Shopify\Auth\Session;
use Shopify\Context;
use Shopify\Utils;

But when I try to print the session info then it throws 500 without no much information.
var_dump($session);

Can anyone explain what is the wrong or how to fix that? For reference I am using this https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest as PHP library.
Note: Please do not suggest other PHP SDK for Shopify.

There's no way we can help given this information. You'll need to examine your web server logs to get the error detail.

@AlexHowansky Is the implementation correct?

I have no idea.

There are nothing in error logs

If you are getting a 500 error from your system, then there should be something about it in the PHP error log. Or is that not what we are talking about here, and you are getting a 500 response from the API (that somehow shows when you dump the content of $session)? Please clarify.

apiKey: '{API_KEY}', apiSecretKey: '{API_SECRET}', - you have inserted the correct values here, without curly braces around them, yes? (This is a syntax often used in documentation, to indicate that a variable value needs to be inserted in such a position, but the {} are not actually part of the values you need to insert there.)
